# Python series repeat values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have the following exercise as introduction to  pandas:

> Create a `Series` with the following content: `index` are days of the month April 2017 (from 1 to 30), and `values` are days of the week which are numbers from 1 to 7 (1st of April was Saturday).

i have tried to do it in the following way:

`days = np.resize(np.arange(1,8), len(np.arange(1,31)))
april = pd.Series(days, index = [np.arange(1,31)])`

it allows me to repeat values 1 to 7 through the indexes, but i don't undesrtand how can i start it from 6 (Sat) instead of 1. or should i do it instead with a for loop to fill series with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum 5 and get module 7 as follows:

```
days = np.resize((np.arange(7)+5)%7+1, len(np.arange(1,31)))
april = pd.Series(days, index = [np.arange(1,31)])
```

Which returns:

```
1     6
2     7
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     6
9     7
10    1
11    2
12    3
13    4
14    5
15    6
16    7
17    1
18    2
19    3
20    4
21    5
22    6
23    7
24    1
25    2
26    3
27    4
28    5
29    6
30    7
dtype: int64
```